# How to create custom authentication in wso2 identity server 5.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to upgrade my WSO2 identity server from 5.0 to 5.3 but I don't know how to add custom authentication  in local and outbound authentication configuration in service provider, for example, I need to add level of assurance(LOA) for my mobile connect project

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement has two aspects.

1. Add custom authentication.
2. LoA

**1. Custom Authentication**

For custom Authentication, you can create your own local or federated authenticators. The documentation are available at [1] [2]

**2. LoA**

This will be available on one of post IS 5.4.0 releases. This will be handled with ACR ("Authentication Context Class Reference")

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+Local+Authenticator

[2] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/04/writing-a-custom-inbound-authenticator-for-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: Actually, the name of OSGi bundle is com.gsma.authenticators-1.0.0 which i am trying to use in my identity server 5.3.0.I have tried all the given solution available on the internet but still, my authentication framework 
 does not automatically detect it during runtime.

Comment: If you got it from [Isuru (https://github.com/VishmikaMaduka/wso2telcohub/blob/master/dialog/gsma-authenticators/pom.xml)] , you will find that it is written for previous version of IS. Most probably it would not have started on IS 5.3.0. You can check that if you start your IS pack with "-DosgiConsole" option. Then type "ls" when server starts. Most probably your bundle would not have activated. In that case, You might want to clone the project, update dependencies and built by yourself.

Comment: can i get your help on skype send your skype id to this email address saif.chader@gmail.com

Comment: I have cloned the project successfully and tried to remove as many error as possible  but when building the project in maven through mvn install i get this error ----> Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.5:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.wso2.custom.authenticator.local: Error(s) found in bundle configuration

Comment: do i have to built the project from the start just point me to a right direction

Comment: Alternatively were you able to try the mobile connect  authenticator. That is only for IS 5.1.0 and 5.2.0, not for 5.3.0 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Mobile+Connect+Authenticator)

Answer (score 0):

Further discussion on Dynamic Authentication flow changes can be found on WSO2 architecture thread.

[Conditional Authentication Support on WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.markmail.org/search/?q=Conditional%20Authentication%20Support%20on%20WSO2%20Identity%20Server#query:Conditional%20Authentication%20Support%20on%20WSO2%20Identity%20Server%20page:1%20mid:hres5xt5vall5vyo%20state:results)

Comment: is there a mediator through which i can achieve parallel threading

Comment: Does this refer ESB or EI ? Identity Server does not have concept of mediator. I would suggest to put different question on respective product if that is the case.